# CLion can't find CMake generated headers?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Going through the [CMake tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake-tutorial):

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
│   └── main.cpp
└── templates
    └── fooConf.h.in
```

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(foo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR src)
set(PROJECT_TEMPLATE_DIR templates)

set(SOURCE_FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_MAJOR 0)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_MINOR 1)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_MICRO 1)
configure_file (
  "${PROJECT_TEMPLATE_DIR}/fooConf.h.in"
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/fooConf.h"
)

add_executable(foo ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

#### templates/fooConf.h.in

```
#define @PROJECT_NAME@_VERSION_MAJOR @PROJECT_NAME@@_VERSION_MAJOR@
#define @PROJECT_NAME@_VERSION_MINOR @PROJECT_NAME@@_VERSION_MINOR@
#define @PROJECT_NAME@_VERSION_MICRO @PROJECT_NAME@@_VERSION_MICRO@
```

#### src/main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "src/fooConf.h"
// Also tried: "fooConf.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << foo_VERSION_MAJOR;
    return 0;
}
```

#### [Error]

```
fatal error: src/fooConf.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `fooConf.h` header file is generated in the *binary* tree (precisely, under `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src/`). So you should issue corresponded `include_directories()` command for use that file in `#include`. E.g.:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
....
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
add_executable(foo ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

**src/main.cpp**

```
....
#include "src/fooConf.h"
```

Comment: any solution for Clion code inspections? there the generated header is still not found

Comment: @arved: I don't know. Could you describe your problem as **another** question? Code introspection is something different than building the project. Moreover, I think that your situation somehow differs from OP one.