# Clion won't index auto-generated ui header files

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5, clion

I was having a look at the [KeepassXC's source code](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc), with Clion as my IDE of choice. After a bit of digging and navigating through the source code, I noticed that one of the source file has the following `#include` directive:

```
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"
```

with a red underline. Hovering over it with my mouse, it says "'ui_MainWindow.h' not found".

The project's `CMakeLists.txt` file provides three build types:

- Debug
- Release
- Release With Debug Info

and, once all three build types are successfully built, the file CLion should look for is in the following location:

```
cmake-build-(debug|release|relwithdebuginfo)
└── src
    └── keepassx_core_autogen
        └── include
            ├── moc_KMessageWidget.cpp
            ├── ui_AboutDialog.h
            ├── ui_CategoryListWidget.h
            ├── ui_ChangeMasterKeyWidget.h
            ├── ui_CloneDialog.h
            ├── ui_CsvImportWidget.h
            ├── ui_DatabaseOpenWidget.h
            ├── ui_DatabaseSettingsWidgetEncryption.h
            ├── ui_DatabaseSettingsWidgetGeneral.h
            ├── ui_DatabaseSettingsWidget.h
            ├── ui_DetailsWidget.h
            ├── ui_EditEntryWidgetAdvanced.h
            ├── ui_EditEntryWidgetAutoType.h
            ├── ui_EditEntryWidgetHistory.h
            ├── ui_EditEntryWidgetMain.h
            ├── ui_EditEntryWidgetSSHAgent.h
            ├── ui_EditGroupWidgetMain.h
            ├── ui_EditWidget.h
            ├── ui_EditWidgetIcons.h
            ├── ui_EditWidgetProperties.h
            ├── ui_EntryAttachmentsWidget.h
            ├── ui_MainWindow.h
            ├── ui_PasswordGeneratorWidget.h
            ├── ui_SearchWidget.h
            ├── ui_SettingsWidgetGeneral.h
            ├── ui_SettingsWidgetSecurity.h
            ├── ui_SetupTotpDialog.h
            ├── ui_TotpDialog.h
            └── ui_WelcomeWidget.h
```

After a couple hours trying to make it work, I've noticed something weird. The red underline will go away (and the code navigation will work too) only if I build the project in Debug mode (i.e. it'll only pick the file from the `cmake-build-debug`).
If I clean the debug build and use the release build, there's no way I can get CLion to pick the file from `cmake-build-release`. Same applies for `cmake-build-relwithdebinfo`.

The code compiles and runs just fine, meaning that the CMake configuration is correct.

Comment: I'm not an expert for CLion (rather for VS2013). However, independently of whether the IDE considers header files or not - it's important that the compiler finds the includes. (Showing them in the project of IDE is just for convenience.) VS2013 comes with Intellisense which remarks things by red lines if it "believes" they are not correct. Mostly, this is fine but in certain cases it fails. I stopped to annoy about this - Intellisense is just not a real C++ compiler. So, at best, I ignore these false positives simply...

Comment: @Scheff I agree, but I have my file full of red lines (i.e. every time a method is invoked upon an object declared in the supposedly missing file). Also, like I said, it's not my code; so code navigation and tooltips could help me understand what the code does.

Comment: In VS2013, a colleague wrote our cmake scripts which (among other things) add all auto-generated files to a separate project (sub-)folder. As already said, this is just for convenience. If a file is `#include`d but not yet created Intellisense may remark it. So, no solution? May be, move the auto-generated header `#include`s to another header which you `#include` in your final destination. So, you don't need to bother about all the red lines in your "primary" source. (This is meant half-seriously. Decide on your own whether this is a solution for you or not.) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by changing Clion environment under `Build, Execution, Deployment > Toolchains` to use compilers installed with Qt instead.
For MinGW 64bit you'll find it under `C:\Qt\Qt5.x.x\Tools\mingwxxx_64`.

Answer (score 1):

this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31293158/192798 helped me find the solution for my case.  i also had the same issue for you where it used to work and then suddenly couldn't find the header file.  for me, i used `target_include_directories` so i had to tell clion to choose the configuration corresponding to the target.  (i was choosing one of the target's dependents.)  then i build, then i can switch to any configuration.

for your case, after switching the configuration, you may need to build to get clion to pick up the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just manually reload cmake project after build.
It works fine for me.

Reference: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-22534